# Matrix valued undefined functions in SymPy

Tags: matrix, sympy

I'm looking for a possibility to specify matrix quantities that depend on a variables. For scalars that works as follows, using undefined functions:

```
from sympy import *
x = Function('f')(t)
diff(x,t)
```

For Matrix Symbols like

```
x = MatrixSymbol('x',3,3)
```

i cannot find an equivalent. There is

```
i,j = Symbols('i j')
x = FunctionMatrix(6,1,Lambda((i,j),f))
```

but this is not what i need as you need to specify the contents of the matrix. The context is that i have equations
which should be derived in time and contain matrix valued elements.
I cannot deal with the elements of the matrices one by one.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything like this. Probably the closest is `FunctionMatrix`. I think you can make your own by subclassing `MatrixExpr`. Pull requests to add it to SymPy are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you want, but I think you want to make a Matrix with differentiable elements. In that case, see if this works for you.

Create a matrix with function elements:

```
X = sym.FunctionMatrix(6,1,lambda i,j:sym.Function("x_%d%d" % (i,j))(t))
M = sym.Matrix(X)
M.diff(t)
```

This results in

```
Matrix([
[Derivative(x_00(t), t)],
[Derivative(x_10(t), t)],
[Derivative(x_20(t), t)],
[Derivative(x_30(t), t)],
[Derivative(x_40(t), t)],
[Derivative(x_50(t), t)]])
```

You may then replace stuff as you need.

Also, it may be preferrable if you populate the matrix with the expressions you need *before* differentiating. Leaving them as undefined functions may make it harder for you to simplify after substitution.